# Xpage: Date validation does not give any validation message

Tags: xpages

I tried a simple date validation, but this "does nothing": I can enter any date I like.

```
<xp:inputText
    value="#{Auftrag.MF_GebDatum_1}" id="MF_GebDatum_11"
    style="width:255px">

    <xp:this.converter>
    <xp:convertDateTime
         type="date">
    </xp:convertDateTime>
    </xp:this.converter>
    <xp:this.validators>
    <xp:validateDateTimeRange
        minimum="1900-01-01T00:00:00"
     message="Please enter a correct date of birth"
     maximum="2100-01-01T00:00:00">
  </xp:validateDateTimeRange>
  </xp:this.validators></xp:inputText>
```

it runs on a german linux server, so I enter dates like 01.01.1811

Thanks for any help, Uwe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example is from the Mastering XPages book. Please try this and see if that helps you:

```
<xp:inputText id="inputText3">
    <xp:this.validators>
        <xp:validateDateTimeRange message="Earliest date is 1 Jan 2011" 
             minimum="#{javascript:new Date(2011,0,1,0,0,0,0)}">
        </xp:validateDateTimeRange>
    </xp:this.validators>
    <xp:dateTimeHelper id="dateTimeHelper1"></xp:dateTimeHelper>
    <xp:this.converter>
        <xp:convertDateTime type="date"></xp:convertDateTime>
    </xp:this.converter>
</xp:inputText>
```